# How to find installed reverse dependencies of a package in cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I need to install newest base package but cabal does not let me to do it

```
cabal install base --reinstall
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
next goal: base (user goal)
rejecting: base-4.8.2.0, 4.8.1.0, 4.8.0.0, 4.7.0.2, 4.7.0.1, 4.7.0.0, 4.6.0.1,
4.6.0.0, 4.5.1.0, 4.5.0.0, 4.4.1.0, 4.4.0.0, 4.3.1.0, 4.3.0.0, 4.2.0.2,
4.2.0.1, 4.2.0.0, 4.1.0.0, 4.0.0.0 (only already installed instances can be
used)
rejecting: base-3.0.3.2 (conflict: base => base>=4.0 && <4.3)
rejecting: base-3.0.3.1 (conflict: base => base>=4.0 && <4.2)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

So I think that when I unregister the dependencies which are holding this package to the old version I can do it

```
ghc-pkg unregister some_annoying_package
```

But how can I find these packages. I found only

```
cabal-db revdeps base
```

which gives me all the dependencies form hackage not just the installed one.

Comment: You cannot reinstall `base` with cabal. If you need to update `base`, you must update your compiler version. In general, if you do `ghc-pkg unregister <pkg>` it will first tell you what will be broken by this (and hence, the dependencies which you need to unregister to unregister `<pkg>`) but this doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: Thanks you @user2407038 you saved my day! I reinstalled ghc and base package is updated!

Comment: Also, reverse dependencies don't prevent you from installing a new version of a package. Multiple installations of the same package (with different version numbers) can happily live alongside each other in GHC's package database. (Modern GHC's can even support multiple installations of the same version of the same library with different dependency trees, though cabal has not yet officially grown support for this feature.)

Comment: @DanielWagner, the Haskell world awaits proper support for said feature with bated breath, sitting on the edges of our seats. That will be a great day. Of course, will still have to deal with the lack of first-class, parameterized modules, orphan instances, the evils if overlapping and closed type families, etc.

Comment: @user2407038 since your comment solved the issue you should submit it as an answer.

Comment: @user2407038 I liked your comment but I can't submit it as an answer so I just posted answer by myself

Answer (score 1):

Updating compiler updated the base package. As explained by user2407038:

> You cannot reinstall base with cabal. If you need to update base, you must update your compiler version. In general, if you do ghc-pkg unregister  it will first tell you what will be broken by this (and hence, the dependencies which you need to unregister to unregister ) but this doesn't apply in this case.